# Mdframed infinite loop within declare theorem style

Tags: errors, mdframed, thmtools, thmbox

First of all, I would like to say that I learned LaTeX by myself, and that my code may not be optimized or I may not master the good practices. Don't hesitate to correct me or to give me advice on this point of view.

I seem to be trying to create a new environment where I can put maths exercises and corrections via Overleaf. I would like these boxes to continue over several pages, even if it means cutting the content into several boxes.

These boxes are quite large; this causes errors in the mdframed package, which cannot cut the content correctly. This leads to an infinite loop and prevents the document from being generated.

The following error is the cause of the interruption: **Package mdframed Warning: correct box splittet fails It seems you are using a non splittable contents on input line 335.**

Here is a minimal code that produces the error:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\title {}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={[}{]},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=red!20, 
            linecolor=red!30, 
            innertopmargin=1.5pt,
            roundcorner=5pt, 
            innerbottommargin=3pt, 
            skipbelow=\parsep, 
            everyline=true } 
]{mytheoremstyle}

\declaretheorem [style=mytheoremstyle, thmbox={style=M, bodystyle=\normalfont,cut=false}, name=algebra exercise]{algebra}

\begin{document}

\begin{algebra}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{algebra}
\end{document}
```

I tried to set the cut=true option, but it didn't change my problem.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: your example gives the error `! Package thmtools Error: \declaretheorem key \`headfont' not known.`

Comment: most of the other keys you use are also undefined. Have you seen this form used elsewhere, is it using a different theorem package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, These keys are only defined when you load `amsthm` before `thmtools`.

Comment: @UdiFogiel ah thanks. post as answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, It does not solve the problem it only remove the errors that you got. It seems there is a bug when using the `mdframed` and `thmbox` keys together with the same theorem.

Comment: After trying to compile the code with `amsthm` loaded before `thmtools`  i had to stop pdflatex as the log file got filled with the line `Package mdframed Info: You first box width is to small
 mdframed fixed it
(mdframed)              on input line 36.
` 
repeatedly

Comment: When I try with either mdframed or thbox it works and in the p5 doc: "Note that for both thmbox and shaded keys, it’s quite possible they will not cooperate with a style key you give at the same time". But I don't know this package, I use tcolorbox

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I finally switched to tcolorbox, but it sadly does not solve the problem...